# Not able to switch between fragment properly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragment on one fragment activity. I have 2 fragments say new and pending but I am having problem while switching from one fragment to another while tapping of button. When I am on pending tab and then click on new tab then sometimes it shows two loader and then it still shows pending page. My both fragments are `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. I am attaching screenshot of the problem while I am tapping on new tab and still showing pending tab with two loader.

**code for switching between fragment**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(neww))
    {
        Fragment newpage = new NewPageActivity();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.framelay, newpage);

        ft.commit();
    }
    else if(v.equals(pending))
    {
        Fragment pendingFragment = new PendingPage();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.framelay, pendingFragment);

        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**now screenshot of problem**

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: Why you dont use FragmentPagerAdapter and ViewPager?

Comment: @PogonetsAnton because it is already build code I am doing bugs resolving in it

Comment: The code looks ok, mqybe the problem is in other part. Where are the loaders placed?

Comment: at the time of fetching data from server means webservice connectivity @adalPaRi

Comment: But I mean where in code. If apparently, you are replaceing fragment in the rigth way, maybe the problem is how you handle the loaders. So, are there one loader within each fragment? Are you handling outside of them?

Comment: I have only one loader in each fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.framelay, fragment);

        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

        ft.commit();
```